# getting NoneType error when attempting to updating label in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have been trying to create a simple GUI in python where you click a button and a count gets incremented and displayed on the screen but when ever i click on the button and the function that increments the count gets run when i try to change what text is in the label using label.configure(text = new_text) it says l is Null, the code is below.

```
from Tkinter import *
count = 0

def click():
    global count
    global l
    count += 1
    l.configure(text = ("Count: " + str(count))).pack(side=RIGHT)

root = Tk()
l = Label(root, text = ("Count: " + str(count)) ).pack(side=RIGHT)
b = Button(root, text="Click", command=click).pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

how can i fix this so it will update the label with the new count variable ?

Answer (score 2):

`Label(...).pack(...)` returns `None` because `.pack(...)` returns `None`. Therefore, `l` and `b` are `None`. You need to separate the creation of the widgets from the layout of the widgets.